# Causing links to pan to and open markers in map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/megatimes/NVDLf/7/

I have a map which is creating multiple markers from an array. 
Below the map are some links which, when clicked, I'd like to cause the map to pan to its respective marker, and open the info window.

Given that I don't want to generate the links themselves as part of the loop that creates the markers, how can I do this?

I'm fairly certain this is a scope issue since the links below the map each open the last item in the locations array but I can't seem to figure out how to get around it.

Thanks

```
var locations = [
    [
    "Location 1",
     "215 West Girard Avenue 19123",
    "39.9695601",
    "-75.1395161"
    ],
    [
    "Location 2",
    "5360 Old York Road 19141",
    "40.034038",
    "-75.145223"
    ],
    [
    "Location 3",
    "1350 W Girard Avenue 19123",
    "39.9713524",
    "-75.1590360"
    ]
    ];


var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.9995601, -75.1395161),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]),
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}


$(function() {
    $('#locations h3 a').each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');    
        })    
      });    
}); 

<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
<div id="locations">
    <h3><a href="#">Location 1</a></h3>
    <p>Arbitrary content about 1</p>

    <h3><a href="#">Location 2</a></h3>
    <p>Arbitrary content about 2</p>

    <h3><a href="#">Location 3</a></h3>
    <p>Arbitrary content about 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6vjwd/2/embedded/result/

uses a createMarker function to associate the infowindow with the marker:

```
function createMarker(latlng, html)
{
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(html);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
return marker;
}
```

And a global array to allow them to be referenced from HTML click listeners.

The external links depend on knowing the order of the locations.  Or if you want to look them up by "name" you could use an "associative" array, with the name as the index.

Indexing the markers by name:

http://jsfiddle.net/6nqj8/1/embedded/result/

Answer (score 3):

I would generate the links using jQuery while generating the markers. You can store the marker object on the link object using jQuery's `.data()` call and add a generic click handler to those links that set the map to the marker's location.

Something kind of like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]),
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

    $('#locations').append($('<a>').append('Location Name').click(function()
    {
        // $(this).data('marker')
    }).data('marker', marker));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunately, creating the links dynamically isn't really on the table because that HTML needs to be edited via a CMS+WYSIWYG. Any ideas on looping through static links on the page?

Comment: use jquery to work out which link was clicked on (think of them as an array of links which you can get from a jquery selector that gets them all), you want to identify the position in that 'array' corresponding to which link was clicked. Then that corresponds to which marker in your array you want to pan to

Comment: @duncan Right. That's conceptually what I've attempted to do but it's geting the _code_ to work which is giving me the problem. The link array is defined at the line starting with `$('#locations h3 a').each(function() {`

Comment: Can we assume that the name of the marker is IDENTICAL to the content of the <a></a> tag, i.e. 'Location 1' === 'Location 1'?

Answer (score 1):

ok, this works for me.  I'm adding each marker to a global variable array called `markers`.  Then whenever a link is clicked, check which link in the array of those links it is by using the jquery [.index() function](http://api.jquery.com/index/), and trigger the 'click' on the corresponding marker (link 1 = marker 1, etc).

Thanks to geocodezip as well for the createMarker function which I've re-used here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map { width: 500px; height: 400px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var marker, map;
var markers = [];

function initialise() {
var i;
    var locations = [
        [
        "Location 1",
         "215 West Girard Avenue 19123",
        "39.9695601",
        "-75.1395161"
        ],
        [
        "Location 2",
        "5360 Old York Road 19141",
        "40.034038",
        "-75.145223"
        ],
        [
        "Location 3",
        "1350 W Girard Avenue 19123",
        "39.9713524",
        "-75.1590360"
        ]
        ];


    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.9995601, -75.1395161),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        markers.push(createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]), locations[i][0]));
    }
}

function createMarker(latlng, html)
{
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(html);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    return marker;
}

$(function() {
    $('#locations h3 a').each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function() {
            // find out which link in the array was clicked (1st, 2nd etc)
            var intLinkClicked = $('#locations h3 a').index($(this));
            google.maps.event.trigger(markers[intLinkClicked], 'click');    
        });
    });    
}); 

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="locations">
        <h3><a href="#">Location 1</a></h3>
        <p>Arbitrary content about 1</p>

        <h3><a href="#">Location 2</a></h3>
        <p>Arbitrary content about 2</p>

        <h3><a href="#">Location 3</a></h3>
        <p>Arbitrary content about 3</p>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```