# gmaps.js - loop through elements and add markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, loops, geocoding

Using **[gmaps.js](http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/examples.html)**
How could i loop through something like (HTML):

```
<h1 id="location">Phuket</h1>

<div class="blist">
    <h3>Some hotel name</h3>
    <p>Adress 1</p>
</div>

<div class="blist">
    <h3>Another hotel name</h3>
    <p>Adress 2</p>
</div>

<div class="blist">
    <h3>Some name</h3>
    <p>Adress 3</p>
</div>

<div class="blist">
    <h3>Some other name</h3>
    <p>Adress 4</p>
</div>
```

..and:

1. GEO-code + Add marker to the map
2. Add name from `<h3>` into each markers popup
3. Add link to each popup that link to it's corresponding  (like an anchor link)
4. Use and add #location for all the GEO-code lockups since each name doesn't say too much without that context

I must use a loop, but haven't found any good examples even though searching for hours. One would think it would be a common use sort of.. :)

**[Check/use jsFiddle base >>](http://jsfiddle.net/bmGEN/)**

Comment: To get the Google maps api to run in jsfiddle, you have to add `type.js` to the end of the URL, otherwise jsfiddle can't determine the type. Whole url is `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&type=.js`

Comment: Here's a way to associate the links with the markers.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13064628/492335

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **gmaps** adapter makes this quite trivial.

```
var map = new GMaps({
    div: '#mapCanvas',
    lat: 0,
    lng: 52,
    zoom: 13,
    width: '400px',
    height: '300px'
});

var popupTemplate = '<div class="popupText"><h3>%1</h3><p>%2</p><p>%3</p></div>';

$(".blist").each(function() {
    var title = $(this).find("h3").text();
    var address = $(this).find("p.address").text();
    var tel = $(this).find("p.tel").text();
    GMaps.geocode({
        address: address,
        callback: function(results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
                map.setCenter(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
                map.addMarker({
                    lat: latlng.lat(),
                    lng: latlng.lng(),
                    title: title,
                    infoWindow: {
                        content: popupTemplate.replace('%1',title).replace('%2',address).replace('%3',tel)
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PJ6dX/1/)**

Notes:

- London hotels used in demo as Geocode was unreliable for addresses in Phuket
- Telephone number field has been added

Comment: This works great for the examples you are giving. Unfortunately i don't have control of the main backend that outputs various values so i get data that is pretty much crap and needs postprocessing.

It would be great just to be able to geolocate by NAME + LOCATION + COUNTRY ie "APK Hotel, Phuket, Thailand". --- Example: [http://jsfiddle.net/w8bvR/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/w8bvR/3/)

Comment: (http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/singlegeocode.html) works quite well with all those Thai streetnames if one uses First value (before first <br>) and add Location + Country ie: "95 Ratchapratanusorn road, Phuket, Thailand". Uses mapsAPI v2 though.. :/

Comment: Tommie, yes I understand. You are having the same problems I had with those Thai addresses, which is why I switched to UK addresses for the demo. You might find a way ahead in **[Geocoding in Thailand](http://t3net-thailand.com/news/articles/story/2011/november/12/geocoding-in-thailand.html)**. It certainly looks promising.

Comment: If I understand the article correctly, then you may need a hidden "mis-spelled" version of each address, to make the geocoding work.

Comment: Interesting article. It seems using the western alphabetic names for Thai cities is a no go. Unfortunately Thai locations aren't the only problem since the script is for a package engine (flights+hotels). Imagine doing misspellings for 50k properties. :) The only solution to such a problem would be to try to lockup stuff via Hotel Name + Location + Country, but i haven't had much luck with that either.

Comment: Agreed, you seem to be at a dead end at the moment. I can't think of a way round Google's limitations in geocoding Thai addresses. `Hotel Name + Location + Country` would be great if it worked. If you can extract a postalcode from the address, then maybe **[geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/)** might be suitable, instead of Google.

Comment: geonames didn't seem to work that well. Actually Bing Maps seems to work a lot better with Hotel Name + Location + Country. I tested 15 hotel names and their location and it got 11 right (via bing.com/maps/). Searching for some example loop at (https://code.google.com/p/jquery-bing-maps/) at the moment.

Comment: Tommie, 11 out of 15 is far more promising. I wonder if for each address, you may need to try several services in cascade until one is found to work. That would be reasonably simple to code.

Comment: In cascade? Sounds more fun then it would be good. However i noticted today -- after requesting long/lat that Google Local actually do work with Hotel Name + Location + Country. Not only did it work but it correctly displayed a hotel that has two similar properties in an area where the names differ greatly depending on what service one use. Anyway to use Google Local for geocoding instead of Google Maps?

Comment: New services seem to emerge almost daily. I wasn't even aware of Google Local. Good one to remember. Thanks for posting Tommie.